# json is not parsed correctly in angular ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

So I use this `$http` for an ajax post in my angular

```
hello.doAjax = function (theData) {       
     var promise = $http({
                        method: 'POST',                                          
                        url : myURL,                                        
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: theData

                    });                
                    return promise;    
}
```

and in my controller I call it like

```
var userid = {"userid" : data.user.id};
var promise = myFactory.doAjax (userid);
```

I always get

Error 500 , `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500`.

In a RestClient if I pass the json part in forms it does not work. If I pass it in raw text like `{"userid":"964"}` it works. Back-end team says that the service is working.

So, is it a problem of json or a bug of angular ? I use angular 1.5.0.

Thanks

Comment: Check the payload sent from devtools Network tab. In Chrome, the headers tab of the POST request will contain _Request Payload_ where you can check what was actually sent.

Comment: By definition an error code 500 is an error at the server end, even if their only error is that they should have returned a different error code. If your request is malformed they should be returned a 400 error.

Comment: Call method like this: `$http({
  
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });` Loot at the output in console and let us know.

Comment: @Satpal Can you be more specific, so I can edit my code correctly?

Comment: @vesse I see no `Request Payload `

Comment: @KhalidHussain Should I put this in the Factory or in the Controller? Thanks

Comment: @slevin, Inside `hello.doAjax = function (theData) {}`. Just append `.then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })` to your `$http` service.

Comment: I alter the code in the controller like `var promise = $http({ ........ }).then(function successCallback(response) { console.log(response); }, function errorCallback(response) { console.log(response); });                
                return promise; ` and I removed the `promise.success and promise.error` parts. I get `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500` I am lost at this point. Any hints? Thanks

Comment: @slevin If you don't see the request payload then nothing was sent in the request body. Is `theData` defined inside you `doAjax` function?

Comment: @vesse Turns out it was a back-end issue, not me. They fixed it. Sorry that I cannot post more info, but I guess it was a PHP/database isssue. Thanks anyway